# SDK probleme in unity 2018

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

There is a problem with my Android SDK installed in my Lenovo laptop, the Android SDK version 25,26,27 and 28 does not work for my unity editor and show's the same error again and again.

expecting:
 "build successful"

What i actually get:

```
" CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to install APK to device. Please make sure the Android SDK is installed and is properly configured in the Editor. See the Console for more details.
C:\Users\LEGION\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s "VWD7N17803000571" install -r "C:\Users\LEGION\Desktop\ARjungleBook.apk"

stderr[
adb: failed to install C:\Users\LEGION\Desktop\ARjungleBook.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed to parse /data/app/vmdl1303990834.tmp/base.apk: AndroidManifest.xml]
]
stdout[
Performing Streamed Install
]
exit code: 1
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of Unity window that pops when this happens. It looks like you SDK is either not installed or is missing a path.

Comment: It's done, I added 3 pictures of the problem and thx again for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with SKD, but not like this one. So I can just give you an advice, but I am not sure if it will fix the problem. However, my problem with SDK got solved by installing an [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) and from there I've installed the SKD and updated a few other things. You can also install just an SDK from attached link, just make sure to scroll down when you click on it.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried both the android studio SDK updating and the tool folder Pasting from the Android package link before and it's pretty much the same result.

Comment: @TarekHalloul you could try & check [this](https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/56033/parsing-package-error-from-unity)

Comment: Np, i am just trying to find a solution. btw.. what's your build platform?

Comment: Its Unity 2018.3.11f1

Comment: great I think I figured it out !! it's in the SDK 29 rc1 and SDK 29 rc2, they are both installed with the SDK 28. we just need to uninstall both SDK 29 versions and keep the Android SDK 28 and it will work just fine. Sorry for the trouble Nikola.

Comment: @TarekHalloul Great! Unfortunately, there is no way for me to test that, but ill keep in mind your solution for future cases :)